# Are there historical examples of countries using pandemics as an excuse for banning protests?

Tags: disease, civil-rights

Australia was [recently in the news](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/25/covid-sydney-police-punish-anti-lockdown-protesters) for restricting the right to protest during a surge in COVID cases:

> Hundreds of fines have been issued and dozens charged in Sydney after
> anti-lockdown protesters marched and clashed with police in what one
> deputy commissioner called “violent, filthy, risky behaviour”.
>
> The Australian prime minister, Scott Morrison, said on Sunday the
> previous day’s protests – in which thousands breached the region’s
> coronavirus measures to protest – were “selfish and self-defeating”,
> adding: “It achieves no purpose. It won’t end the lockdown sooner.”

Are there any pre-COVID examples of countries using a pandemic (or a pandemic like spread of disease) as an excuse to curb the right to protest?

Comment: Public health and sanitation is frequently mentioned as a problem when discussing protest camps, e.g. here: https://prologue.blogs.archives.gov/2020/07/15/the-1932-bonus-army-black-and-white-americans-unite-in-march-on-washington/

Comment: Berlin example is actually the best example for extreme bigotry, as it was exactly irrelevant 'how' demonstrations went down, as the CSD example showed: more people, closer together, no NPIs measures adhered to at all, allowed to finish the party. So we know it was exactly and only about the topic: try a protest against the measures, adhere to nonsensical measures decreed, still get whacked so bad that UN torture committee gets alarmed. Organize sth w/o relation or consequence for the policies, and see it heralded as "see, we still _allow_ 'protests'"… 1st comment here is obsolete and wrong.

Comment: The crux of any answer would be demonstrating that the sanitary restrictions are indeed an "excuse" and not a honest attempt to improve public health(no matter if you believe those measures are proportionate or excessive). As such, I would expect evidence of a double standard (acts against the government/ruling party are banned while acts in support are allowed, despite having the same characteristics)

Comment: @SJuan76 And that is indeed easy for Berlin: ['Senator rejoices to make Berlin queer capital'](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/csd-berlin-2021-im-blog-65-000-leute-bei-parade-groesste-demo-in-der-coronakrise/27450424.html) while [some scratch their heads over blatant double standards](https://www.bild.de/politik/inland/politik-inland/tausende-feiern-in-berlin-freiheit-nur-wenn-es-politisch-genehm-ist-77181800.bild.html) Problem is that this fine example is the one thing to compare any _pevious_ instances to.

Comment: The second demostration I mentioned was on the same day and the same topic: [A number of other demonstrations, which, according to their title, were *also directed against the politics of the corona pandemic*, have not been banned.  A good 100 people came to an event in Berlin-Wedding on Saturday, **and 120 vehicles took part in a car parade in Charlottenburg**.](https://www.rbb24.de/panorama/beitrag/2021/07/berlin-querdenker-demos-verboten-polizei-corona.html). So my statement is factualy correct and verifiable.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Where did you mention it? This seems to be your first comment in this post.

Comment: @SJuan76 It was the 1st comment of this thread, but seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Zimbabwe did so in [2018](https://news.trust.org/item/20181009144759-k8zwu).

More generally, public health and sanitation is one of the concerns regularly raised against protest camps, e.g. in this case in the US in [1932](https://prologue.blogs.archives.gov/2020/07/15/the-1932-bonus-army-black-and-white-americans-unite-in-march-on-washington/):

> As summer temperatures rose and sanitary conditions in the camps deteriorated, pressure to end the protest mounted.